# jQuery ajax: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax

I read some posts related to this problem but unfortunately, no solution found for my case

i hit an error *jquery.min.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined* when i make a following request jQuery ajax

**ajax_test.htm**

```js
<script src="common_test.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
//String.prototype.trim = function(){return
//(this.replace(/^[\s\xA0]+/, "").replace(/[\s\xA0]+$/, ""))}
$(document).ready(function() {
 formDownloadFile();
});

function formDownloadFile() {
 // jQuery ajax:
 alert("sending ajax...");
 jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax_test2.htm',
  dataType: "text",
        data: {}
 })
    .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { // Succes
  console.log('done => data: ', data, ', textStatus: ', textStatus, ", jqXHR: ", jqXHR);
    })
 .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { // fail
  console.error('fail => jqXHR: ', jqXHR, ', textStatus: ', textStatus, ", error: ", errorThrown);
 })
 .always(function() { //
  
 });
 
 alert("ajax sended");
}
</script>
```

**common_test.js**: this library contains many javascript functions but i discovered that my problem is caused by the following function

```js
... my stuffs ...
String.prototype.trim = function(){return (this.replace(/^[\s\xA0]+/,
   "").replace(/[\s\xA0]+$/, ""))};
... my others stuffs ...
```

**ajax_test2.htm** have nothing!

when i remove incluse **common_test.js** from **ajax_test.htm**, i have no more problem!
i don't understard why?

thanks a lot
best regards
dsea

Comment: `common_test.js` has to have more content than that ?

Comment: But there's no `toLowerCase` in it, so it can't produce that error

Comment: What is ajax_test2.htm?

Comment: had you tried it? it is an error from jquery.min.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Basically What you are trying to do here is to replace the string in common_test.js to lower case letters and so it produce the errors.. One way to solve this is:

```
String.prototype.trim = function(){return (this.replace(/^[\s\xA0]+/,
   "").replace(/[\s\xA0]+$/, "").toLowerCase())};
```

You need to explicitly convert your string to lower case, you do so by explicitly defining `toLowerCase();`

```js
<script src="common_test.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
String.prototype.trim = function(){return
(this.replace(/^[\s\xA0]+/, "").replace(/[\s\xA0]+$/, "").toLowerCase())}
$(document).ready(function() {
 formDownloadFile();
});

function formDownloadFile() {
 // jQuery ajax:
 alert("sending ajax...");
 jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax_test2.htm',
  dataType: "text",
        data: {}
 })
    .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { // Succes
  console.log('done => data: ', data, ', textStatus: ', textStatus, ", jqXHR: ", jqXHR);
    })
 .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { // fail
  console.error('fail => jqXHR: ', jqXHR, ', textStatus: ', textStatus, ", error: ", errorThrown);
 })
 .always(function() { //
  
 });
 
 alert("ajax sended");
}
</script>
```

Comment: no, no! the toLowerCase is ready a standard function of object string [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolowercase.asp). In my case, i don't even why there is this error! when i uncommend //String.prototype.trim in *ajax_test.htm* (and removing incluse *common_test.js*), i have no problem! For understanding, could you try it? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it's caused because of my defined function "String.prototype.trim" is on 2 lines:

```js
String.prototype.trim = function(){return
(this.replace(/^[\s\xA0]+/, "").replace(/[\s\xA0]+$/, ""))}
```

if I put on one line :

```js
    String.prototype.trim = function(){ return (this.replace(/^[\s\xA0]+/, "").replace(/[\s\xA0]+$/, "")) }
```

or with the 'good' following syntax:

```js
String.prototype.trim = function(){
 return (this.replace(/^[\s\xA0]+/, "").replace(/[\s\xA0]+$/, ""))
}
```

i have no more problem
hope it helps for someone :)

best regards